# Draw a line on an image using angle and center point using Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm facing a little issue in my code. I have a dataframe of coords and angels.
I want to draw a line from a certain xy coords to the edge of the image on a certain angle (say 45 degree).

How can I do that using PIL? Looping over x2 = x + length*cos(angle) doesn't look like a good solution (but I might be wrong here).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: a nice understandable (but not the fastest) way is to define a 3x3 rotation matrix for that angle (see internet) and define the x-axis direction as (1,0) and transform it with the rotation matrix (either opencv function perspective transform or matrix multiplication with homogenous coordinates), then you have the DIRECTION vector of your line. If necessary normalize it to get vector length 1. Now you can draw a line from center - length/2.0*direction to center + length/2.0*direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for posting your solution. I've found a good one.

```
import math

def get_coords(x, y, angle, imwidth, imheight):

    x1_length = (x-imwidth) / math.cos(angle)
    y1_length = (y-imheight) / math.sin(angle)
    length = max(abs(x1_length), abs(y1_length))
    endx1 = x + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    endy1 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))

    x2_length = (x-imwidth) / math.cos(angle+180)
    y2_length = (y-imheight) / math.sin(angle+180)
    length = max(abs(x2_length), abs(y2_length))
    endx2 = x + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle+180))
    endy2 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle+180))

    return endx1, endy1, endx2, endy2
```

Then I just draw a line between (endx1, endy1)  and (endx2, endy2).

If you have a better solution, I would be very interested to see it.

Comment: Yes - using sin and cos for this case beats a full 3x3 transformation matrix - that would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The code from Abdulaziz has issues, e.g. when the angle is 0 or 180 degrees due to how trigonometric functions behave at these angles. Here is an updated version:

```
def get_line_endpoints(x, y, angle, imwidth, imheight):

    if angle == 0:
        return (imwidth, y), (0, y)
    elif angle == 180:
        return (0, y), (imwidth, y)
    elif angle == 90:
        return (x, 0), (x, imheight)
    elif angle == 270:
        return (x, imheight), (x, 0)

    x1_length = (x-imwidth) / math.cos(angle)
    y1_length = (y-imheight) / math.sin(angle)
    length = max(abs(x1_length), abs(y1_length))
    endx1 = x + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    endy1 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))

    x2_length = (x-imwidth) / math.cos(angle+180)
    y2_length = (y-imheight) / math.sin(angle+180)
    length = max(abs(x2_length), abs(y2_length))
    endx2 = x + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle+180))
    endy2 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle+180))

    return (int(endx1), int(endy1)), (int(endx2), int(endy2))
```